# Javascript Drag & Drop script performance

Tags: javascript, animation, drag-and-drop, mousemove, requestanimationframe

I've written a little drag and drop script in Javascript, I'm aiming to make it as efficient as possible (element following the cursor at the exact spot it was grabbed and no lag spikes) to accomplish this you usually try to limit the amount of times your move function gets fired (throttling the mousemove event) but I tried some other method, thing is I'm not sure if it's actualy doing what I'm expecting.

This is how I'm handling it;

Firstly, on mousedown, a requestAnimationFrame loop starts

```
    var handleMovement = function(){
        self.ele.style.top = self.dragElPos.pageTop+'px';
        self.ele.style.left = self.dragElPos.pageLeft+'px';
        self.animFrame = requestAnimationFrame(handleMovement);
    }
```

And secondly, the mousemove event calls this function

```
    var setCoordinates = function (e) {
            self.dragElPos.pageTop = (e.pageY-self.dragElPos.innerTop);
            self.dragElPos.pageLeft = (e.pageX-self.dragElPos.innerLeft);
    }
```

All this does is store the position in some object, the handleMovement() function retrieves this and due to the animation loop the element gets moved.

The behaviour I'm expecting is that requestAnimationFrame is optimizing the loop so the animation runs smoothly, but because the coordinates are being set by some other function I wonder if it knows when it's optimized.

It looks pretty smooth, but if it's not being optimized I'd rather use mousemove throttling.

P.S. Browser compatibility is no concern.

Comment: Since the movement of the mouse is driving the movements of the element, I would say calling your handlemovement function within the mousemove event would be the most efficient. The way you're handling it, it gets called 60 times per second (presumably) regardless of whether the mouse is moving.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson The animation loop is moving the element

Comment: So are you trying to reduce lag, smooth the visual dragging or something else? One smoothing factor would be to keep the rAF running and set a flag in `mousedown` to alert rAF to start animating and clear the flag in `mouseup` and `mouseout`.

Comment: @user3310293 I understand how the code is working, I mentioned the animation loop moving the element in my comment. As I said, the function gets called 60 times per second due to the `requestAnimationFrame()` call